# Moment JS: Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I'm getting `Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.`
But I'm a newbie I cannot figure out how to fix it so the above message disappear.
I think the problem lies in these two lines but I'm not sure.

```
var nextMonth = moment(moment(year + "-" + month + "-1")).add(1, "months").format("MM");
var nextYear  = moment(moment(year + "-" + month + "-1")).add(1, "months").format("YYYY");
```

I have already checked https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 and [Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263380/deprecation-warning-moment-construction-falls-back-to-js-date) but neither seems to work on my problem.

I would like to know where in this calculation I should tell the format to the moment or at least how to make this calculations in the right format so the warning disappears.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263380/deprecation-warning-moment-construction-falls-back-to-js-date

Answer (score 12):

Actually I found the problem.

By just adding new Date() to both calculations, it normalized again.

```
var nextMonth = moment(new Date(year, month - 1, 1)).add(1, "months").format("MM");
var nextYear  = moment(new Date(year, month - 1, 1)).add(1, "months").format("YYYY");
```

I hope it help others!

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263380/deprecation-warning-moment-construction-falls-back-to-js-date

Comment: The comment thread in the issue has a pretty good explanation as well, now: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407

Comment: Moment’s usage is so widespread that it’s impossible to deprecate the current version over time. Check out this [post][1] on alternative options Migrating away from moment.js
https://www.panayiotisgeorgiou.net/migrating-away-from-moment-js/