# Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am attempting to convert this datetime

> 150423160509 //this is utc datetime

To the following format:

> 2015-04-24 00:05:09 //local timezone

by using the moment.js

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');


var a = moment.tz('150423160509', "Asia/Taipei");
console.log( a.format("YYYY-MM-DD H:m:s") );
```

but it gives me this error

```
Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263380/deprecation-warning-moment-construction-falls-back-to-js-date)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell moment how to parse your date format, like this:

```
var parsedDate = moment.utc("150423160509", "YYMMDDHHmmss");
var a = parsedDate.tz("Asia/Taipei");

// I'm assuming you meant HH:mm:ss here
console.log( a.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") );
```

Comment: Fixed that for you. :)

Answer (score 5):

This is what i found when I typed "moment construction falls back to js Date" in Google. (From a post of [Joe Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263380/deprecation-warning-moment-construction-falls-back-to-js-date))

> To get rid of the warning, you need to either:
>
> - Pass in an ISO formatted version of your date string:
>
>   `moment('2014-04-23T09:54:51');`
> - Pass in the string you have now, but tell Moment what format the string is in:
>
>   `moment('Wed, 23 Apr 2014 09:54:51 +0000', 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY
>     HH:mm:ss ZZ');`
> - Convert your string to a JavaScript Date object and then pass that into Moment:
>
>   `moment(new Date('Wed, 23 Apr 2014 09:54:51 +0000'));`
>
>   The last option is a built-in fallback that Moment supports for now,
>     with the deprecated console warning. They say they won't support this
>     fallback in future releases. They explain that using new Date('my
>     date') is too unpredictable.

Hope that helped ;)