# Moment: Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am receiving that error in the browser console, and this is all I have regarding moment in my system:

```
moment(slip.gameLineObj.date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
```

should I update moment ? or what should I do ?

**UPDATE**

`(slip.gameLineObj.date)` returns `2015-06-10T20:05:00.000Z`

momentjs version according to bower.json `"moment": "2.10.3"`

Comment: What's the value of `slip.gameLineObj.date`? Also, possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263380/deprecation-warning-moment-construction-falls-back-to-js-date

Comment: @milz I did a console.log(console.log(slip.gameLineObj.date) and returns 2015-06-10T20:05:00.000Z

Comment: Not sure what you're issue is... Take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/r9ytp1as/). It's working correcty. What version of momentjs are you using?

Comment: and you're using which version of moment.js? (please add that information to your post)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans "moment": "2.10.3"

Answer (score 1):

You should read [this issue on github](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407).

> moment construction using a non-iso string is deprecated. What this
>   means is you can safely do:

```
> moment("2014-04-25T01:32:21.196Z");  // iso string, utc timezone
> moment("2014-04-25T01:32:21.196+0600");  // iso string with timezone
> moment("2014 04 25", "YYYY MM DD"); // string with format
```

*Long story short:*
Now you should specify format of your date in string or your string with date should be formatted by one of iso formats.