# Angular function to check if time is within 45mins of given time and if now is after time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to 'angularJS' and having a hard time creating a function that will check if a give 'time' is less than 45 minutes from `now` and also if the `time` is in the past that is `now` is after `time`

```
function checkTime(time) {
    var date = new Date();
    var date1 = new Date((date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + time);
    var minutes = (date1.getTime() - date.getTime()) / (60 * 1000);
    return (minutes > 40 || (minutes < 0 && minutes > -1395));
}
```

This is what I have so far, it checks that `time` is not greater than `45 mins` from `now`

Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: angular does not have a special date and time handler. You should  checkout [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) that will help.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with momentjs.

[Angular directive for moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment).

[Moment js docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

First install moment through bower:

```
bower install angular-moment moment --save
```

Include moment in your app:

```
<script src="components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
```

( If you are using grunt, run grunt serve and it will automatically add these scripts, since you are using `--save` during `bower install` )

Add module angularMoment to Your app.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['angularMoment']);
```

Now you can use momentjs in your controllers.
I suggest moment, because it's easier to operate on dates than with pure javascript.

**Your problem** is to find it one point in time is before or after now in a specified time ( 45 mins ). It seems to me that imagine you have circle with radius. Radius is 45 mins and now is in the middle of circle. Then everything inside this circle is fine and everything outside is wrong. 
[image]

You also want to know if something is in past, so is on a left side of a circle.

So lets assume that middle is algebraic **0**.

**n** is circle radius. ( 45 mins )

If **t** is argument ( given time ), then to check if it is inside:

```
f(t) = n - t
if f(t) is between 0 and t then it belongs on a right side. 
if f(t) is between t and 2t then it belonds and in on left side ( past ).
```

With this preparation, time to implement in momentjs:

```
function checktime(time){
    var now = moment(new Date());
    var later = now.add(45*60,'seconds');
    var time = moment(new Date(time));
    var ft = later.millisecond() - time.millisecond();
    if ( ( ft > 0 ) && ( ft < 2700000 ) )//45*60*1000
        return false;//future
    if ( ( ft > 2700000 ) && ( ft < 2*2700000 ) )
        return false;//past
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I want the function to return a single `true` or `false` if one or both conditions are `true` then return `false` if none of the conditions are `true` then return `true`

Comment: Getting errors, don't I need to do this? If you wish to use `moment()` in your services, controllers, or directives, simply inject the moment variable into the constructor.

Comment: so inject it through dependency injection. code is just a scratch.

Comment: getting this in console; `Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.`

Comment: an edit was made. Use new Date():http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263380/deprecation-warning-moment-construction-falls-back-to-js-date

Comment: Function is always returning `true`

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

```
var date = new Date();
var date1 = new Date((date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear()+ " " + time);

var diff = date.getTime() - date1.getTime();
var minutes = diff.getMinutes();
return (minutes > 40 || (minutes < 0 && minutes > -1395));
```

Comment: @moh.ABK I udpated answer.basically I used `getMinutes` method to get time in minutes