# What is this warning in my console & how to get rid of this message?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In one of my project I have notice this message in my console but I am not sure what this really mean & how to fix it. Any clue ?
[image]

It says :

> jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread
>   is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
>   experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.send @
>   jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
>
> moment-with-locales.js:326 Deprecation warning: moment construction
>   falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in
>   upcoming major release. Please refer to
>   https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.printMsg @
>   moment-with-locales.js:326

Comment: look for your ajax calls - make sure they are async.

Comment: It would really make things easier if you copied the text instead of the screenshot.

Comment: synchronous httprequest freeze ui

Comment: as for the moment one, read the github issue.

Comment: The first is related to `$.ajax` `async` option. The second is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23376374/2151050)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the XMLHttpRequest warning, remove:

```
async: false
```

in any of your ajax calls