# Moment.js Timezone not converting unless I pass in date as striing

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am having trouble with converting a datetime to the proper timezone
I do not understand why this is functioning like this.

```
d = "Thu Apr 26 2018 21:09:11 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"

moment.tz(d.toString(), this._timezone).format('MM/DD/YYYY h a')
```

returns `04/26/2018 3 pm`

```
moment.tz(d, this._timezone).format('MM/DD/YYYY h a')
```

returns `04/26/2018 10 pm`

Also `moment.isMoment(d)` returns `false`

also if I convert `d` to an ISO string before adjusting the TZ the TZ doesn't adjust

```js
var d = "Thu Apr 26 2018 21:09:11 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)";

console.log(moment.tz(d.toString(), 'America/Chicago').format('MM/DD/YYYY h a'));

console.log(moment.tz(d, 'America/Chicago').format('MM/DD/YYYY h a'));

console.log(moment.isMoment(d));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.16/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: it takes date input as string. what is wrong with that ?

Comment: when I pass in toString I get a deprecation warning "Value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format"

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263380/deprecation-warning-moment-construction-falls-back-to-js-date). It's because parsing strings is inconsistent. Browser to browser it may differ. So the moment expect you to specify the format of your string.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic detection of non-ISO strings has been deprecated. See [here](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/) for more information. The salient point is:

> This deprecation warning is thrown when no known format is found for a
>   date passed into the string constructor. To work around this issue,
>   specify a format for the string being passed to moment().

So if you want to *reliably* parse the given string, you'll need to specify the format at parse-time as follows:

```
moment.tz(d, '<format here>', this._timezone);
```

I'm not sure exactly how to format your whole date correctly, but something like this should work:

```
var DATE_FORMAT = 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z'
```

```js
var d = "Thu Apr 26 2018 21:09:11 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)";
var DATE_FORMAT = "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z"

console.log(moment.tz(d.toString(), DATE_FORMAT, 'America/Chicago').format('MM/DD/YYYY h a'));

console.log(moment.tz(d, DATE_FORMAT, 'America/Chicago').format('MM/DD/YYYY h a'));

console.log(moment.isMoment(d));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.16/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rajits information is correct but it was not the cause of the "odd" behavior.

although `Thu Apr 26 2018 21:09:11 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"` looks like a string it was actually an instance of a javascript date object.
`new Date()` was called on a UTC timestamp which resulted in that "string" therefore when passing the date instance directly to moment, moment could handle it but when turning it into a string with `toString()` it was changed into just a plain string.

Also calling `new Date()` on a UTC timestamp it automatically convert this timestamp into the browsers (clients computer) local timezone. So if you want to change your timestamp to an arbitrary timezone make sure not to call `new Date()` before.

Comment: Whilst I suspected you'd get the behaviour you described if you passed a `Date` object to moment, you explicitly offered code that said you were passing a string. `d = "Thu Apr 26 2018 21:09:11 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"` is _unambiguous_.