# momentjs : Deprecation warning error in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need help I'm getting a warning on my code that has a value provided is not in a recognized ISO format.

Here's the warning error

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format.
>   moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable
>   across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date formats are discouraged
>   and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to
>   http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>   Arguments: [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _useUTC: true,
>   _l: undefined, _i: 2016-9-26 19:30, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]

Here is my code:

```
var componentDetails = {
  componentName: comp.componentName,
  companyName: comp.employerdetails.companyname,
  fromDate: (comp.employmentdetails.fromdate)?moment(comp.employmentdetails.fromdate).format("DD-MM-YYYY"): comp.employmentdetails.fromdate,
  toDate: (comp.employmentdetails.todate&&comp.employmentdetails.todate!='Present')?moment(comp.employmentdetails.todate).format("DD-MM-YYYY"): comp.employmentdetails.todate,
  designation: comp.employmentdetails.designation,
  currency: comp.employmentdetails.currency,
  ctc: comp.employmentdetails.lastctc,
  period: comp.employmentdetails.period,
  senderName: req.session.loggedInUser.firstName+" "+req.session.loggedInUser.lastName,
  empCode: comp.employmentdetails.empid,
  reason: (comp.others?comp.others.reasonforleaving: "")
};
```

so the above part only im getting the error what can i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263380/deprecation-warning-moment-construction-falls-back-to-js-date)

Answer (score 1):

These values `comp.employmentdetails.fromdate` OR `comp.employmentdetails.todate` are not in **ISO-8601** format. Below are the formats:

**An ISO 8601 string requires a date part.**

```
2013-02-08  # A calendar date part
2013-W06-5  # A week date part
2013-039    # An ordinal date part

20130208    # Basic (short) full date
2013W065    # Basic (short) week, weekday
2013W06     # Basic (short) week only
2013050     # Basic (short) ordinal date
```

For more information check [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)

Comment: k but in my code where I need to put the format?please tell me bez already I changed this format but wont works

Comment: @Prakash from where are you getting `comp.employmentdetails.fromdate` and `comp.employmentdetails.todate` and in what format your are getting these values?

Comment: @Prakash The format need to be passed as second param on moment construction. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51388623/4593057)