# moment deprecation warning: dates accessor is deprecated. Use date instead

Tags: node.js, momentjs

#### Moment.js deprecation warning

Error info:

```
Deprecation warning: dates accessor is deprecated. Use date instead.
Arguments: 
Error
    at Moment.dates (/Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/node_modules/moment/moment.js:320:98)
    at eval (eval at compile (/Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:549:12), <anonymous>:61:39)
    at returnedFn (/Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:580:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:223:34)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:437:10)
    at View.render (/Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at /Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/routes/index.js:248:18
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/ephraimguo/Documents/OST_work/booking_Prototype/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

Tried using moment object to replace Date() object but still having the same error.
I would like to know how to solve this error, although it is not affecting the performance, cluster cannot be implemented if having any errors.

Comment: Can you share the code that is giving this error? Try to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Some where you using dates instead of date .check properly routes/index.js  line : 248 in your project directory

Answer (score 0):

From Moment version 2.6.0, `dates(), years()` are deprecated  and from version 2.10.0, `months()` is deprecated. So its recommended to use `date(), month(), year()`.

To remove the deprecation warnings, [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51388623/4593057)