# Moment.js Deprecation Warning - Value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I am trying to fetch previous date using moment and getting depreciation warning.
Below is the snippet

```
const prevDate = () => {
    return moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}
```

Currently runnning this application on a Linux system.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263380/deprecation-warning-moment-construction-falls-back-to-js-date-when-trying-to

Comment: @HamidShoja But I am not passing any date inside moment(). I am not getting the solution required.

Comment: what version of moment are you using? because this code works fine without any warning

Comment: @AshishModi "moment": "^2.24.0",